# Prevent input field from showing a character, that doesn't match a regular expression

Tags: javascript, html

I'm checking every character typed in an input field, against some regular expression. The first character in the input box, might have different "criteria" than the second character, and so on. For example: i want to allow the digits 1-3 in the first character, and 5-9 in the second.

I'm comparing the event.key against the regular expression. All nice and well, but i don't know how to prevent a "false" value from appearing in the input field. A wrong value should result with...well, absolutely nothing.

The html "pattern" attribute of course won't help me, being that i need to perform this check on every key press.

How can i prevent a typed character from actually being "assimilated" into the input value?

EDIT: here is some code i have so far..:

```
 element.bind('keyup', (e) => {


            var patt = new RegExp(/[0-3]/);
            var res = patt.test(e.key);
            console.log(res)
            if(!res){                
              //do something...          

            })
```

Comment: Please share your first approach.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've added some code..

Answer (score 2):

`return false` if the pressed key matches your regExp.

Comment: Nah, doesn't prevent the character from showing up in the field. I also tried preventDefault(), in case the comparison fails

Comment: Well you are using the wrong event listener. You cant prevent something that already happened... You need to check which key is pressed with `keydown` , with keyup there is no step back :D

Answer (score 1):

Here i want to prevent the spaces from the textbox,

```html
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
      var uname = $("input#username");
      var func = function () {
        uname.val(uname.val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
        uname.val(uname.val().toLowerCase());
      }
      uname.keyup(func).blur(func);
  });
</script>
```

You can apply you logic in this case.

Comment: I cant vote down but this is VERY hacky. You are immediately deleting input made by the user. You should definitely not make this.. and UI/UX Team will probably punch you if you do so :D

Comment: yes @CristianS. definitely,But we don't know for what kind of case OP wants so,